# Excel Vlookup or formula

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

Can someone suggest a formula in Excel for the below;

I have the following data in a sheet1 where users have multiple roles assigned to them, users have multiple roles and each is listed in a separate row

```
A----------B
User 1 - Role 1
User 1 - Role 2
User 1 - Role 5
User 2 - Role 2
User 2 - Role 5
User 3 - Role 1
User 3 - Role 3
```

In another sheet2 I have all unique user names where I want the data from Sheet 1 to be listed

```
A----------B-------C---------D
User 1 - Role 1 - Role 2 - Role 5
User 2 - Role 2 - Role 5
User 3 - Role 1 - Role 3
```

Comment: Do you want a vb.net solution, a vba solution or just an excel formula?

Comment: Excel formula .

Comment: Thank you. I have edited your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula in sheet2-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7)/(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7=$A1),COLUMN(A$1))),"")
```

If you have `Office365` then you can simplify it by `Transpose()` and `Filter()` formula-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$7,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$7=A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible with formulas, but VBA would do it as follows

```
Dim Lrow as Long
Lrow = shtFrom.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
Dim RoleCount as Long
Dim shtFrom as Worksheet, shtTo as Worksheet

Set shtFrom = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set shtTo = Sheets("Sheet2")

For x = 1 to shtTo.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
    RoleCount = 0
    For y = 1 to Lrow
        If shtFrom.Cells(y, 1).Value Like shtTo.Cells(x, 1).Value Then
            RoleCount = RoleCount + 1
            shtTo.Cells(y, RoleCount + 1).Value = shtTo.Cells(x, 2).Value
        End If
    Next y
Next x
```